# How to assign different style to search button in Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

i am looking to find out how i can have 2 search buttons on 1 page but with different colors. Currently within my header I have a search button in white as this sits on a background color.

Within my content, if somebody is within the search page the search box and button both show up but they both sit on a white background hence the button and input box cannot be seen and i am not sure how i can have 1 style for the one button and another for the search button in the header.

I have tried to place another style within the search-bar.liquid file (snippets) but this affects both so i'm not sure how i can fix this.

My Code:

```
<form action="/search" method="get" class="input-group search-bar" role="search">
  {% comment %}<input type="hidden" name="type" value="product">{% endcomment %}
  <input type="search" name="q" value="{{ search.terms | escape }}" placeholder="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}" class="input-group-field" aria-label="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn icon-fallback-text">
      <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="fallback-text searchbutton">{{ 'general.search.submit' | t }}</span>
    </button>
  </span>
</form>
```

If somebody could please advise would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assign them different classes and then style them as you need :|

Comment: Hi Dennis, I tried to do that but not sure how i split the above code to target a different style...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get" action="/search">
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input  type="submit" value="Search" />
```

use this form.